# What is SubscribeOn() doing here?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm teaching myself reactive programming by flailing my way through random problems and asking stupid newbie questions with no shame. While figuring out how thread scheduling works, I managed to stump myself. While I'm pretty sure this code doesn't make logical sense, I also can't understand what's going on. Figuring that out would probably help me out. Here's the code:

```
var testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
var newThreadScheduler = new NewThreadScheduler();

var emitter = new Subject<string>();
testScheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1), () => emitter.OnNext("one"));
testScheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2), () => emitter.OnCompleted());

var subscription = emitter.SubscribeOn(newThreadScheduler)
                            .Subscribe(
                                item => Console.WriteLine(item),
                                error => Console.WriteLine(error),
                                () => Console.WriteLine("Complete!")
                            );

testScheduler.AdvanceBy(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).Ticks);

Console.WriteLine("DONE.");
Console.ReadLine();
```

What I *expected* was maybe:

```
one    
DONE.
Complete!
```

With possible interleaving, as I wasn't quite sure what SubscribeOn() would do. What I got instead was:

```
DONE.
Complete!
```

What exactly is happening here? Why didn't the item get produced before the completion? ObserveOn() works as I expected in this case, and I understand why: it's running the delegates on some other thread and they can interleave with "DONE." So what exactly is SubscribeOn() doing?

Comment: I know nothing of Reactive, but looking at your code, you subscribed on `newThreadScheduler`, but all of your work and schedules are triggered against the `testScheduler`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is simply a race condition.

If we rip back all the code to just

```
var emitter = new Subject<string>();
emitter.OnNext("one");
emitter.OnCompleted();

var subscription = emitter
                            .Subscribe(
                                item => Console.WriteLine(item),
                                error => Console.WriteLine(error),
                                () => Console.WriteLine("Complete!")
                            );



Console.WriteLine("DONE.");
Console.ReadLine();
```

We get the same result. 
By using a `Subject<T>` you will not get any caching behavior, with the exception for the the `OnCompleted` notification.

The `SubscribeOn` operator will schedule any subscription work to be done on the provided `IScheduler` instance.
In the case of subscribing to a `Subject<T>` there is almost not work to be done.
It is almost as simple as registering a callback to a list of callbacks.

Scheduling work on to a `NewThreadScheduler` will create a new thread, and then create an internal event loop to process the scheduled work. 
This pretty quick, but does require creating a new thread, an EventloopScheduler and performing the context switch to the new thread.

In your example, you schedule the `OnNext` and `OnCompleted` notifications on a `TestScheduler`.
You then `SubscribeOn` with a `NewThreadScheduler`.
Following that, you start to process all the scheduled work for the `TestScheduler` instance.
The processing of these *virtually* scheduled items, is just iterating over the scheduled items, execting the delegate and advancing a virtual clock. 
This is incredibly fast.

To be more concrete, the code below is analogous to what you have written

```
var newThreadScheduler =  new NewThreadScheduler();

var callbacks = new List<Action<string>>();
newThreadScheduler.Schedule(()=>callbacks.Add(str=>Console.WriteLine(str)));

foreach (var callback in callbacks)
{
    callback("one");
}

Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

Here we simply have a list of callback actions (call them subscribers or observers).
We then asynchronously schedule on a new thread the addition of one of these callbacks.
And then immediately iterated the callbacks and send the string "one" to each of them.
The result is

```
Done
```

The `NewThreadScheduler` just isn't given enough time to start up a new thread, schedule the action, and then execute that action, before the main thread can iterate over the collection.

So there are a couple of guidelines that I think you are failing to follow:
 1) Avoid Subjects ;-)
 2) Don't mix threading and unit tests. I assume the presence of the `TestScheduler` is because you are testing this. You could however use two instances of `TestScheduler` e.g. background and foreground instances.

To be more helpful, I would offer the positive guidance of suggesting that you just remove the second scheduler from your test. 
Use the `TestScheduler` instance in your `SubscribeOn` operator.

Next I would suggest replacing the use of subjects+scheduling with the use of the `TestScheduler`'s Observable sequence factory methods i.e. `CreateColdObservable`.
Finally I dont know if the advancing to the speicifc time of 1s gains anything, over just using the `Start` method.
I think that would reduce the noise and use of the magic value 1s.

```
var testScheduler = new TestScheduler();

var source = testScheduler.CreateColdObservable<string>(
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1).Ticks, "one"),
    ReactiveTest.OnCompleted<string>(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2).Ticks));

var subscription = source.SubscribeOn(testScheduler)
                            .Subscribe(
                                item => Console.WriteLine(item),
                                error => Console.WriteLine(error),
                                () => Console.WriteLine("Complete!")
                            );

testScheduler.Start();

Console.WriteLine("DONE.");
Console.ReadLine();
```

The only issue now is that the `SubscribeOn` call is pretty redundant.

FYI: Code for the `NewThreadScheduler` - 
https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/master/Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.PlatformServices/Reactive/Concurrency/NewThreadScheduler.cs

Comment: Thanks for this very detailed answer, this wasn't really production code so much as just trying to figure out how things worked, so that made it a little weird! It sounds like mixing TestScheduler with 'real' schedulers causes more problems, so I need to adjust how I experiment.

Comment: Yes agreed. Either 'virtualise'  time using a testscheduler/historicalscheduler or use the real ones